# Здесь возможно и употребление единого знака — тире с запятой, (—) но нежелательно

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно?

> Здесь возможно и употребление единого знака — тире с запятой, но нежелательно.

> Здесь возможно и употребление единого знака — тире с запятой, — но нежелательно.

Comment: Если это приложение, то одно тире; если вставка или пояснение, то два. Думаю, автор решает, чем считать эту конструкцию. Мне больше нравится вариант, в котором это считается пояснением.